# Display a Message on Closing an Activity

Tags: android

So, when the user force closes an activity, I want to display a custom message (Toast) to the user. Any suggestions? I tried putting the Toast in my `onPause()` / `onStop()` methods, but they cause the program to crash.

And no, I'm not trying to spam the user with messages everytime he/she force closes an activity. I just want to display the Toast when a *particular* activity is closed.

Comment: What do you mean by force close

Comment: As in when the user press the home or back buttons

Comment: @ManishBurman "force close" is usually associated to killing a process. Pressing home or back does not force anything, they are expected ways to exit an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                toast(getString(R.string.exit_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
             }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm feel like kicking myself for not thinking of that.